# How to change the default setFlash () in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

How to change the default setFlash () in CakePHP ?
How or where change this default element:

```
<div id="flashMessage" class="message">
My message.
</div>
```

Necessary:

```
<div id="myid" class="myclass">
My message.
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages):

Create the file app/View/Elements/flash_custom.ctp and build our custom flash element:

```
<div id="myid"><?php echo $message; ?></div>
```

Then call `setFlash()` with those parameters:

```
<?php 
$this->Session->setFlash('My message.', 'default', array('class' => 'myclass'));
```

The output in your template from using `$this->Session->flash()` with the above example would be then:

```
<div id="myid" class="myclass">My message.</div>
```